# In Ionic with React, how do I put a text input below an output area that fills the space above, scrolling as needed?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Here is my code as it stands:

```js
import {IonContent, IonHeader, IonInput, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar} from '@ionic/react';
import './HomeTab.css';

const HomeTab: React.FC = () => {
  let tableStyle = {
    height: "100%",
  };
  let inputTdStyle = {
    height: "15px",
  };
  let outputDivStyle = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    overflow: "auto",
  }
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>example</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">example</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <table style={tableStyle}>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div style={outputDivStyle}>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit aliquet mauris, et dictum mauris
                vulputate sit amet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
                fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id congue ante. Fusce vel tellus velit. Nam ut ex vel augue faucibus
                viverra. Sed vitae hendrerit lectus. Integer auctor eros sit amet dolor sollicitudin, sed sagittis neque
                feugiat. Maecenas vel enim non sapien lacinia ultricies. Sed nec ante euismod, lacinia risus vel,
                interdum nulla. Etiam in suscipit turpis, nec finibus purus. Integer semper justo risus, vitae pulvinar
                velit dignissim a. Sed placerat dignissim dolor, sit amet condimentum metus bibendum vel. Vivamus
                blandit, tortor id congue vestibulum, diam nisl convallis metus, et viverra libero felis eu odio.

                Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate nunc vel velit accumsan, vitae bibendum quam consectetur. Donec viverra
                ante ac est tempus, et molestie eros vulputate. Nulla quis turpis non elit rhoncus bibendum. Donec eget
                dolor sed urna sagittis vulputate. Sed ac sapien euismod, blandit magna vel, laoreet mi. Vestibulum
                congue dolor id nulla malesuada, ut porttitor lectus commodo. Sed finibus ipsum quis velit varius, eget
                dapibus justo commodo. Aliquam a urna vel odio venenatis scelerisque. Nulla aliquet, mi sed lacinia
                dictum, quam sapien aliquam enim, ac euismod ex quam non ipsum. Vivamus ut fringilla lacus, vel sagittis
                purus. Aliquam ut est eget purus commodo sagittis. Donec ut rhoncus lacus.

              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style={inputTdStyle}>
              <IonInput
                className="textinput"
                placeholder="Enter text"
                color="primary"
                mode="ios"
              ></IonInput>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default HomeTab;
```

It gets the job done... with a table. I've heard that using tables for layout is bad, so I'd like to know how to do this without using a table.